# In Pokemon X, can you delete a HM move and still use it on the world map?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Okay, so I have just gotten back into Pokemon, just managed to evolve my Charmeleon into a Charizard. It wants to learn Wing Attack and I was just wondering if you can delete that move but still keep the skill? Is it possible to delete a HM move like Cut, but still be able to use the ability it grants? (cut down trees)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, once you get rid of a move you can't use it battle sense or out of battle. It's gone and it can't be used. To get rid of a HM move you can go to a "Move Delete Tutor" in Dendemille town, in a House, up and right from the Pokemon Center (next to some stairs), is the Move Deleter and the Move Reminder. The Move Deleter is to the left side of the house after entering, and the reminder is in the right side of the house. Dendemille town is after the 6th badge I believe.
So until then anything you teach to your Pokemon you keep, so just be careful

Comment: Oh okay, so if I manage to get to this move deleter and remove the HM, will that become usable again with the same pokemon with the move reminder? Also, can the Move reminder be used to gain moves you turned down when the pokemon were leveling up?

Comment: @Aurora-Spark No, the move reminder only teachers Pokemons moves they have had the chance to learn before, but were either passed over or overwritten. You could just use the HM to teach them the moves again, though

Comment: Oh okay, well that makes it a whole lot simpler. So just to clarify, if I delete one of my charizard's existing moves, say, Fire Fang, and I get to the Move deleter, have him remove Cut, would I then be able to get back the move Fire Fang to fill the Empty Slot? (provided a better move doesnt come along)

Comment: Yes, and if you want cut back just use the HM again, it's good to have a "HM Slave" Pokemon, these are Pokemons that can learn most of the HM's and are used when needed just to use the HM

Comment: Brilliant, that's taken a lot off my mind, you guys are the best, props to you helping out a newbie so quickly and effectively :)